# Redirecting USB data to Ethernet/TCP/IP port

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a program on the PC using C/C++ to enable USB redirection to TCP/IP port. On the other end, there's a server that receives the TCP packets and parses the USB data.

The basic usage of the program is to make the program thinks it's connected to the remote device using TCP rather than USB.

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to build the PC to redirect the USB to the TCP/IP, what knowledge is needed for this project? and how do you think I should go about doing this PC program?

Comment: This is a totally unrealistic question. It's kind of like: "I've been thinking of building a four-lane suspension bridge to carry truck traffic across stuff. Should I be using some kind of steel?" You don't even have enough knowledge yet to explain the scope of what you're trying to do or know what such a description would consist of. (For example, you didn't specify a platform. Do you even know what affect that has?)

Comment: @david oh my apologies on this, what u said is right I'm still very new in terms of programming, I tried googling but I couldn't find the right terms or keywords that was hitting what I needed. That's probably why I needed to ask over here for some guidence. Probably u could kindly tell me what is needed?

Comment: You need to decide on what platforms you're going to support, what devices you're going to support, and exactly what the server on the other end is supposed to be able to do to the devices.

Comment: This is, simply put, not a feasible project for an inexperienced developer. Creating it will require extensive experience working with USB, and in developing device drivers for your operating system.

Comment: @david the platform i'm planning to support tentatively would be Windows, the server would be just a USB data relay that does somethg like this : http://www.solovatsoft.com/USB_Redirection_Driver.html

Comment: @duskwuff hmm... well, I thought it was worth learning up XP since I have to start learning somewhere I thought I can start learning up right now! What would u advice me to start learning with? USB or developing a device driver?

Comment: Did you notice this part, " Deep understanding of USB protocols and data ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are going to need external libraries for this, as there is no solution in the stl (no easy solution i should say). USB support is tricky. The winapi has solutions irrc, however linux requires some hacky solutions. there might be a cross platform library for this. googling something such as "c++ usb library" could produce results. as for the other, you are going to need a networking library. typically i just use sfml, since im familiar with it, but there are no shortage of options. then just learn how to use each library to do what you want